# Como puedo traer datos aleatorios con node js desde mongo

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

Quisiera saber como puedo traer datos aleatorios desde la base de datos mongo con nodejs estoy tratando de traer productos aleatorios, he buscado por internet pero no encuentro solución

este es mi código

```
const productsEight = await Products.find().limit(8).sort({$natural:-1});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De la siguiente manera me funciona pero no muestra la imagen es como si no encontrar la ruta de la imagen

```
 const productsEight = await Products.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 8 } }]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta manera estoy llamando la imagen

```
src={`data:image/png;base64,${btoa(new Uint8Array(review.url_img_producto.data.data).reduce(function (data, byte) {return data + String.fromCharCode(byte);}, ''))}`}
```

json del segundo código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

json del primer código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como lo puedo solucionar este problema muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Si, debería ser con $sample. Ya el tema de la imagen si depende... que te devuelve la consulta que si muestra las imagenes y que te devuelve la consulta que no muestra las imagenes? como se renderizan esas imagenes? donde las estás mostrando? pon el código relevante a esta parte para poderte ayudar.

Comment: @Pipe hola buenas tardes de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda he actualizado el post muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No has agregado el json que te devuelve la consulta cuando la imagen si funciona... y el json que te devuelve la consulta cuando la imagen no te funciona

Comment: @Pipe Edite el post colocando los dos json la primera imagen es con el aggregate y la segunda imagen es con el find(). los dos json son diferentes, con el find la data de la imagen son solo números y con el aggregate son muchos caracteres, no se si tengo que llamar la imagen de una forma diferente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Ahi está la respuesta... para el segundo código no existe `url_img_producto.data.data`... ya te llega un string... entonces lo que debes hacer con el segundo código es algo como ```src={`data:image/png;base64,${review.url_img_producto.data)`}```

Comment: @Pipe acabe de probar tu código me funciono perfectamente muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Tal parece que estás almacenando la imagen en la DB. Mala elección, mi sugerencia es que la almacenes en el sistema de archivos y en la DB sólo guardas la ruta relativa a la imagen. Saludos